# Why does implicit conversions for Writable doesn't work

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

`SparkContext` defines a couple of implicit conversions between `Writable` and their primitive types, like `LongWritable <-> Long`, `Text <-> String`.

- TEST CASE 1：

I am using the following code to combine small files

```
  @Test
  def  testCombineSmallFiles(): Unit = {
    val path = "file:///d:/logs"
    val rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile[LongWritable,Text, CombineTextInputFormat](path)
    println(s"rdd partition number is ${rdd.partitions.length}")
    println(s"lines is :${rdd.count()}")
  }
```

The above code works well, but If I use the following line to get the rdd, it will result in a compiling error:

```
val rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile[Long,String, CombineTextInputFormat](path)
```

It looks that the implicit conversion doesn't take effect. I would like to know what's wrong here and why it isn't working.

- TEST CASE 2：

With following code that is using sequenceFile, the implicit conversion looks working(Text is converted to String, and IntWritable is converted to Int)

```
 @Test
  def testReadWriteSequenceFile(): Unit = {
    val data = List(("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("C", 3))
    val outputDir = Utils.getOutputDir()
    sc.parallelize(data).saveAsSequenceFile(outputDir)
    //implicit conversion works for the SparkContext#sequenceFile method
    val rdd = sc.sequenceFile(outputDir + "/part-00000", classOf[String], classOf[Int])
    rdd.foreach(println)
  }
```

Compare these two test cases, I didn't see the key difference that make's one work,and the other doesn't work.

- NOTE:

The `SparkContext#sequenceFile` method that I am using in the TEST CASE 2 is:

```
  def sequenceFile[K, V](
      path: String,
      keyClass: Class[K],
      valueClass: Class[V]): RDD[(K, V)] = withScope {
    assertNotStopped()
    sequenceFile(path, keyClass, valueClass, defaultMinPartitions)
  }
```

In the `sequenceFile` method,it is calling another sequenceFile method, which is calling hadoopFile method to read the data

```
  def sequenceFile[K, V](path: String,
      keyClass: Class[K],
      valueClass: Class[V],
      minPartitions: Int
      ): RDD[(K, V)] = withScope {
    assertNotStopped()
    val inputFormatClass = classOf[SequenceFileInputFormat[K, V]]
    hadoopFile(path, inputFormatClass, keyClass, valueClass, minPartitions)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

To use implicit convertions `WritableConverter` is needed. 
For example :

```
   def sequenceFile[K, V]
       (path: String, minPartitions: Int = defaultMinPartitions)
       (implicit km: ClassTag[K], vm: ClassTag[V],
        kcf: () => WritableConverter[K], vcf: () => WritableConverter[V]): RDD[(K, V)] = {...}
```

I can't see anywhere in [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html) `sc.newAPIHadoopFile` used that. so its not possible.

Also, Please verify  you have used `import SparkContext._` (I cant able to see the imports in your post)

Pls. have a look at `WritableConverters` in [`SparkContext`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala) which has below code

```
/**
 * A class encapsulating how to convert some type `T` from `Writable`. It stores both the `Writable`
 * class corresponding to `T` (e.g. `IntWritable` for `Int`) and a function for doing the
 * conversion.
 * The getter for the writable class takes a `ClassTag[T]` in case this is a generic object
 * that doesn't know the type of `T` when it is created. This sounds strange but is necessary to
 * support converting subclasses of `Writable` to themselves (`writableWritableConverter()`).
 */
private[spark] class WritableConverter[T](
    val writableClass: ClassTag[T] => Class[_ <: Writable],
    val convert: Writable => T)
  extends Serializable

object WritableConverter {

  // Helper objects for converting common types to Writable
  private[spark] def simpleWritableConverter[T, W <: Writable: ClassTag](convert: W => T)
  : WritableConverter[T] = {
    val wClass = classTag[W].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[W]]
    new WritableConverter[T](_ => wClass, x => convert(x.asInstanceOf[W]))
  }

  // The following implicit functions were in SparkContext before 1.3 and users had to
  // `import SparkContext._` to enable them. Now we move them here to make the compiler find
  // them automatically. However, we still keep the old functions in SparkContext for backward
  // compatibility and forward to the following functions directly.

  implicit def intWritableConverter(): WritableConverter[Int] =
    simpleWritableConverter[Int, IntWritable](_.get)

  implicit def longWritableConverter(): WritableConverter[Long] =
    simpleWritableConverter[Long, LongWritable](_.get)

  implicit def doubleWritableConverter(): WritableConverter[Double] =
    simpleWritableConverter[Double, DoubleWritable](_.get)

  implicit def floatWritableConverter(): WritableConverter[Float] =
    simpleWritableConverter[Float, FloatWritable](_.get)

  implicit def booleanWritableConverter(): WritableConverter[Boolean] =
    simpleWritableConverter[Boolean, BooleanWritable](_.get)

  implicit def bytesWritableConverter(): WritableConverter[Array[Byte]] = {
    simpleWritableConverter[Array[Byte], BytesWritable] { bw =>
      // getBytes method returns array which is longer then data to be returned
      Arrays.copyOfRange(bw.getBytes, 0, bw.getLength)
    }
  }

  implicit def stringWritableConverter(): WritableConverter[String] =
    simpleWritableConverter[String, Text](_.toString)

  implicit def writableWritableConverter[T <: Writable](): WritableConverter[T] =
    new WritableConverter[T](_.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]], _.asInstanceOf[T])
}
```

***EDIT :***

> I have updated my question and give two test cases, one works, the
>   other doesn't, but I can't figure out what's the difference between
>   them.

#### `WritableConverter`s are needed for implicit conversion.

- Testcase1 i.e  `val rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile...(path)` implicit conversion was ***NOT*** done in side `SparkContext`. That's why if you pass Long it wont work, will give compiler error
- TestCase2 i.e  `val rdd = sc.sequenceFile(...)` you are passing `ClassOf[...]` directly.  ***If you are passing `ClassOf[...]` no implicit conversion is needed since these are classes not Long value or String Value..***

Comment: Thanks @ram-ghadiyaram for the reply. I have updated my question and give two test cases, one works, the other doesn't, but I can't figure out what's the difference between them.

Comment: Thanks @ram-ghadiyaram. The SparkContext#sequenceFile,which has 3 overloading method,  that I am using doesn't have any implicit things. Please see my updated question(at the end)

Comment: this  method is calling another method which has implicit conversion done

Comment: Thanks @ram-ghadiyaram. Please see the end of the question that I have updated. The method doesn't call the method that has implicit conversion

Comment: if I got it correctly.. in test case 2 ,  you are using `val rdd = sc.sequenceFile(outputDir + "/part-00000", classOf[String], classOf[Int])` . if thats the case then you have passed direct classes for ex classOf[String] (which are expected by the method thats why no error) instead of primitives.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148297/discussion-between-ram-ghadiyaram-and-tom).

Comment: " I think there should implicit conversion happens some where?"
if you are passing classes then no need for implicit converstion. since they are classes
if you are passing Long or String as value then implicit convertion is needed